# Jacoco Maven plugin giving a 'Connection Refused' error while manual dump works fine - What am I missing?

Tags: jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I am using a TeamCity setup to run our Maven project. Our Maven app starts as a Docker container with the following setting for adding the jacoco runtime jar as well as the java string

```
        <profile>
            <id>download-jacoco</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <jacoco.javaagent.string>-javaagent:/opt/config/jacoco/jacoco-agent.jar=output=tcpserver,address=*,port=6300</jacoco.javaagent.string>
            </properties>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <!-- Download jacoco runtime jar -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>download-jacoco-agent</id>
                                <phase>generate-test-resources</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>copy</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <artifactItems>
                                        <artifactItem>
                                            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                                            <artifactId>org.jacoco.agent</artifactId>
                                            <version>0.8.8</version>
                                            <classifier>runtime</classifier>
                                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jacoco</outputDirectory>
                                            <destFileName>jacoco-agent.jar</destFileName>
                                        </artifactItem>
                                    </artifactItems>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
```

After my Docker container starts, I am able to manually trigger the coverage dump from the VM host using only:
`java -jar jacococli.jar dump --destfile jacoco.exec`

However, if I want to use the jacoco-maven-plugin to trigger the same dump via Maven on TeamCity, I get connection refused:

```
<plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.8.8</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>dump</id>
                            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>dump</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <destFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-calc-${rtp.run.its.group}.exec</destFile>
                                <address>localhost</address>
                                <port>6300</port>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    </plugin>
```

TeamCity says that:

```
18:12:59   [DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.8:dump from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.8, parent: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@277050dc]
18:12:59   [DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.8:dump' with basic configurator -->
18:12:59   [DEBUG]   (f) append = true
18:12:59   [DEBUG]   (f) destFile = /opt/buildagent/work/c455c53d7acdc9bf/testing-plan/calculation-its/target/jacoco-calc-lserv.exec
18:12:59   [DEBUG]   (f) dump = true
18:12:59   [DEBUG]   (f) port = 6300
18:12:59   [DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: com:calculation-its:12.6.0-SNAPSHOT @ /opt/buildagent/work/c455c53d7acdc9bf/testing-plan/calculation-its/pom.xml
18:12:59   [DEBUG]   (f) reset = false
18:12:59   [DEBUG]   (f) retryCount = 10
18:12:59   [DEBUG]   (f) skip = false
18:12:59   [DEBUG] -- end configuration --
18:12:59   [INFO] Connecting to localhost/127.0.0.1:6300
18:12:59   [INFO] Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

I don't know what else should I check since manual dump from the VM host is working.

my Docker app has port 6300 exposed already

[alin.negut@CI-X04 ~]$ java -jar jacococli.jar dump --address localhost --port 6300 --destfile jacoco.exec
[INFO] Connecting to localhost/127.0.0.1:6300.
[INFO] Writing execution data to /home/alin.negut/jacoco.exec.

If I try to dump from the TeamCity agent container, I am able to reproduce it:

```
root@27507f849cb2:/home/buildagent# java -jar jacococli.jar dump --destfile=jacoco.exec --port 6300
[INFO] Connecting to localhost/127.0.0.1:6300.
[WARN] Connection refused (Connection refused).
```

I was able to trigger it using the name of the container

```
root@27507f849cb2:/home/buildagent# java -jar jacococli.jar dump --address=rtp-ci-calculation-v12-mssql-2019 --destfile=jacoco.exec --port 6300
[INFO] Connecting to rtp-ci-calculation-v12-mssql-2019/172.18.0.3:6300.
[INFO] Writing execution data to /home/buildagent/jacoco.exec
```